# Issues using the Code Migration to migrate to Magento CE v2.2.3 w/ PHP 7.1

Tags: magento2.2, composer, code-migration, php-7.1

I'm attempting to use the *[code-migration](https://github.com/magento/code-migration)* toolkit provided by Magento to assist in our migration to **Magento CE *v2.2.3*** (from *v1.9.3.4*), but after I clone the [latest branch](https://github.com/magento/code-migration/commit/8f9f833832ac5d8f859dd94fa6098cae2a6ccf93) and execute either `composer install` or `composer update`, I get errors stating that the version of PHP I have installed (**v7.1.17**) isn't supported, and instead lists the PHP version requirements of `php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0`. However, according to the [requirements listed in the README](https://github.com/magento/code-migration/blob/develop/README.md#system-requirements), any PHP version greater than 5.5x is supported.
*(Exact output of composer commands pasted at the bottom)*

I'm somewhat new to Composer, but I notice that the [version requirements in the composer.lock for PHP](https://github.com/magento/code-migration/blob/develop/composer.lock#L31) is set as `~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0`, but the [PHP version requirement found in the *composer.json* file](https://github.com/magento/code-migration/blob/develop/composer.json#L21) is set as `~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0|~7.1.0`. Should the composer.lock file reflect the same PHP version requirements as the *composer.json*?

I haven't found too much about this, with the exception of an [open issue](https://github.com/AdFabConnect/magento2gdpr/issues/13) I found under a separate repository which is pretty similar.

I found [another issue](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1246) where a user encountered a similar issue (unrelated repo), and was able to resolve it by executing `composer update --lock`. I attempted executing the same command only to have Composer run into 6 more "Problems". Output below.

### Composer Commands & Output

```
-bash-4.2$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/framework 100.0.12 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.12].
    - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.

-bash-4.2$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository https://pear.php.net
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/framework 100.0.20 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.19 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.18 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.17 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.16 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.15 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.14 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.13 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.11 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.10 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.8 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.7 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.6 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.5 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
-bash-4.2$ composer update --lock
Loading composer repositories with package information
Initializing PEAR repository https://pear.php.net
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package zendframework/zend-stdlib (locked at 2.4.0, required as 2.5.0) is satisfiable by zendframework/zend-stdlib[2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package zendframework/zend-code (locked at 2.4.0, required as 2.5.0) is satisfiable by zendframework/zend-code[2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - The requested package zendframework/zend-http (locked at 2.4.0, required as 2.5.0) is satisfiable by zendframework/zend-http[2.4.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 4
    - The requested package sebastian/phpcpd (locked at 2.0.0, required as 2.0.4) is satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 5
    - The requested package pdepend/pdepend (locked at 2.0.6, required as 2.5.0) is satisfiable by pdepend/pdepend[2.0.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 6
    - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.20 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.19 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.18 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.17 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.16 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.15 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.14 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.13 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.11 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.10 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.8 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.7 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.6 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.5 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.17) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
```

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks!

### Update

I found a [SO post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/magento-2-code-migration-installation-using-git?rq=1) with a similar issue (problem using Composer with code-migration repo). I followed the steps provided in [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103918/54016) but encountered the same errors regardless.

Comment: Justin, it seems that https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html supports 7.1.* for Magento2.  I recommend  you open a Github issue for this https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: Camdixon, I actually did, I just opened it under the code-migration repository, since thats the repo thats throwing the error. https://github.com/magento/code-migration/issues/90

Comment: Camdixon, I also posted the question on the Magento forums: https://tinyurl.com/y79xctxa

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is the best solution, but it works to add `|~7.1.0` to composer.lock.