# Why code migration tool is missing in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, migration, magento2-migration-tool, code-migration

Why code migration tool is missing here? -> https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Is there any code migration tool or process available?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/magento-2-code-migration-installation-using-git

Comment: The code migration tool is not available now. It is showing page not found. https://github.com/magento/code-migration

Comment: It is removed now. No other code migration tool is available as of now.